# How to aggregate time series data while grouping by another field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've got documents that look like:

```
{u'memory_virtual': {u'percent': 55.6}, u'name': u'Device #1', u'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 52, 18)}
{u'memory_virtual': {u'percent': 55.6}, u'name': u'Device #2', u'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 52, 16)}
{u'memory_virtual': {u'percent': 55.7}, u'name': u'Device #1', u'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 46, 56)}
{u'memory_virtual': {u'percent': 55.7}, u'name': u'Device #2', u'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 46, 54)}
{u'memory_virtual': {u'percent': 55.7}, u'name': u'Device #1', u'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 41, 34)}
{u'memory_virtual': {u'percent': 55.7}, u'name': u'Device #2', u'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 41, 32)}
```

I've been using the following group stage to aggregate the data into 15 minute intervals:

```
{
    '$group': {
        "_id": {
            "$toDate": {
                "$subtract": [
                    {"$toLong": "$datetime"},
                    {"$mod": [{"$toLong": "$datetime"}, 1000 * 60 * 15]}
                ]
            }
        },
        'mean': {'$avg': '$memory_virtual.percent'}
    },
}
```

With output that looks like:

```
{u'_id': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 18, 0), u'mean': 26.10909090909091}
{u'_id': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 45), u'mean': 28.98695652173913}
```

My question is, how do I get this to group by the 'name' field as well?  So that I'd get output that looks like:

```
{u'_id': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 18, 0), u'name': 'Device #1', u'mean': 26}
{u'_id': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 18, 0), u'name': 'Device #2', u'mean': 27}
{u'_id': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 45), u'name': 'Device #1', u'mean': 27}
{u'_id': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 17, 45), u'name': 'Device #2', u'mean': 28}
```

I am not sure if this matters but for reference I am using pymongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `name` also in `_id` of `$group` stage

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            date: {
                "$toDate": {
                    "$subtract": [
                        {"$toLong": "$datetime"},
                        {"$mod": [{"$toLong": "$datetime"}, 1000 * 60 * 15]}
                    ]
                }
            },
            name: "$name"
        },
        "mean": {"$avg": "$memory_virtual.percent"}
    }
}
```